# Back to previous activity having a dialog box in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I have an android application with 2 screens. And I set a dialogue box while going from first screen to second screen. My code is:

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating User");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.show();

            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("invoiceid", invc);
            it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            startActivity(it);
            //finish();

        }
```

When running code, On clicking the back button it shows the dialogue box and goes to the first screen.
Now I want to show the first screen directly on clicking the back button without showing the dialogue box.How is it possible?

And how to clear the first screen if there is a text box in it ?

Comment: Try pDialog.dismiss() before startActivity(it);

Comment: Dismiss your dialogue in onPostExecute and then start your activity. Don't start in onPreExecute.

Comment: Have you specified the hierarchical parent for the second activity?

Comment: @Rakshit Nawani : Thanks... It works fine. I have one more question..... How to clear the first screen if there is ant text box ?

Comment: @Rose :happy to help, posted my answer below please accept and upvote it if it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pDialog.dismiss()` before `startActivity(it);`
If you want to clear  any data in any TextBox in the first Activity set text to that EditText **""** before shifting any activity it will clear the data at EditText.

Answer (score 3):

**public void dismiss ()**

> Added in API level 1. Dismiss dialog, removing it from the screen.
>   This method can be invoked safely from any thread. Note that you
>   should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is
>   dismissed.

```
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        it.putExtra("invoiceid", invc);
        it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        startActivity(it);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        it.putExtra("invoiceid", invc);
        it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        pDialog.dismiss();
        startActivity(it);
```

Comment: 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK'  why do you need that?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 pDialog.dismiss() before startActivity(it)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to dismiss the `dialogBox` before shifting it to other Activity.
Add your intent in onPostExecute

```
pDialog.dismiss();
```

Then call your intent

```
Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("invoiceid", invc);
            it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            startActivity(it);
```